# Make my iPhone invisible to iTunes and password protect the connection

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, jailbreak

I am wondering, is there any application available in the App Store for making my iPhone invisible to iTunes?  Which means, when I connect my iPhone to PC through USB cable, iTunes will automatically detect my iPhone.  But, I want a password protected connection, because when an iPhone is stolen, any person can connect iPhone to iTunes and restore all the data.

So I would like to protect from this ... when my iPhone connects to iTunes, it should ask for a password.

**Is there is any way to do this by using private API**, or jailbreak API, or is a ready made application available?

Comment: Actually here I posted the Question for seeking help for develop a application ourselves. at the end of the question , I mentioned that, is there is any API available for developing app like this. so I swear that , this is not off topic of programming question. it's completely programming question only.

Comment: I would recommend to move developers questions up (somebody could have read it only halfway.

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2010/05/18/password-protect-iphone-and-ipad-backups/

Comment: @VictorRonin thank you Victor.. I will do it now.

Comment: @sosborn thank you for your suggestions. as you mentioned link , that can protect only some sensible data right ? But I would like to protect entire connections, and also I need to protect all the apps which i was installed already.

Answer (score 2):

iTunes uses AFC daemon to communicate with iPhone through USB. So obvious thing to do is to prevent this daemon from launching automatically. You can use `launchctl` to do this.

On device start (or right after iPhone was connected to PC) you need to execute

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.afcd.plist
```

When you connect your device to PC iTunes will display error saying in can't connect to the device. Then your application can ask for a password and when it's entered correctly you can launch AFC daemon back like this

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.afcd.plist
launchctl start com.apple.afcd
```

The only problem with this method is you need to relaunch iTunes, otherwise he will not detect device even after you started AFC daemon.

**UPDATE**

Found a proper solution. There is IOKit.framework API to turn on/off USB -http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-502/usb_device.subproj/IOUSBDeviceControllerLib.h

Here is the code:

```
//Declarations
IOReturn IOUSBDeviceControllerCreate(CFAllocatorRef allocator, IOUSBDeviceControllerRef* deviceRef);
IOReturn IOUSBDeviceControllerForceOffBus(IOUSBDeviceControllerRef device, int enable);    

...

//Create controller
IOUSBDeviceControllerRef device = NULL;
IOUSBDeviceControllerCreate(NULL, &device);

//Turn USB off
IOUSBDeviceControllerForceOffBus(device, 1);

//Turn USB on
IOUSBDeviceControllerForceOffBus(device, 0);

//Free controller
CFRelease(device);
```

When USB is turned off your mac/PC will no longer see the device. It will be like you physically disconnected it. iTunes, Xcode, file browsers - all of them will no longer see it.

When USB is turned on your mac/PC will detect the device. You don't need to replug it. All the software will detect it automatically like device was physically pluged in.

I should warn you that when USB is turned off you cannot turn it back on without using the code above. If you stuck with it only device restart will help.

Tested only on iOS 7 but it looks like those functions are available since iOS 4.